# Azure VM WS2008R2 IIS Excel Download

Tags: excel, iis, azure, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2

We are facing a peculiar problem in our website which is hosted in a azure VM IIS in classic mode.

IIS setting timeout is 40 mins.We have a page where user is able to configure and download excel report .

when user clicks a button in a page in asp form base website the request calls a process in the backend oracle server and in .net we converted that data-set into physical excel file using NPOI.dll and then add that file in response .

this is working fine when the total process takes less time < 2/3 min and from trace log we can see that every steps is performed till end.and the user gets the file as download.file size <15 mb

But when the process takes more time then also every steps is performed ,file size >50mb and log writing also completes but there is no response in the user end. the waiting circle is just keep spinning.

We tried different option but nothing works but same thing works in our local physical servers with less h/w resource

Can anyone please give us any suggestion to solve this issue ?

Comment: when downloading large albums, imgur will take your email address, and then send you a link to the file they created. That could be an option.

Comment: This is not related to image download .this is related to excel download

Comment: I know it's not imgur, but if there is likely to be a timeout, then offering a download link would solve the problem